# remove google text from google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to remove text from google maps that appear bottom left corner of the map .

is this can be done or not ?

if done then how can i do that 
[image]

Comment: no other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you are not allowed to do that. You can take a look at Brand Features License section in [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en)

> In using Google Brand Features, you will not:
>
> remove, distort, or alter any element of a Google Brand Feature
> (including squeezing, stretching, inverting, or discoloring).

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done: http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

> Can you give me permission to show your content without attribution,
>   or put the attribution at the end of my book/movie/TV show?
>
> Without exception, we require attribution when Content is shown.
>   Please do not ask to negotiate this requirement. If you are unwilling
>   to meet our attribution requirements, contact our data provider(s)
>   directly to inquire about purchasing the rights to the Content
>   directly. See our [attribution page](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html) for more information.

Comment: yes i see this so for this i have to contact with data providers right no other way to do this

Comment: Seems like thats the only way out - Powered by Google